# shinyproxy: how to add shiny-server app to yml file

Tags: r, shiny, shinyproxy

I have a shiny-server image which contains many shiny apps and I also modified many configuration file in it such as `shiny-server.conf` and `odbc.ini`.

**1. The running container of my shiny-server image**

```
PS C:\Users\10612033> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES

1a626dc37fa9        65b9953e8066                    "/usr/bin/shiny-se..."   7 days ago          Up 7 days           0.0.0.0:3838->3838/tcp    sharp_golick
```

**2. Get into the container:**

```
PS C:\Users\10612033> docker exec -it 1a626dc37fa9 bash
```

**3. shiny apps listed here:**

```
root@1a626dc37fa9:cd /srv/shiny-server/
root@1a626dc37fa9:/srv/shiny-server# ls
01_hello       04_mpg      07_widgets  10_download   Auto_DTC_old2  closewindow  GPIO_app_old  PowerSeq_app2  SIV_Test_Analysis  SIV_Usage_V1_2     src_compare_tool3
02_text        05_sliders  08_html     11_timer      Auto_DTC_Web   EMC_Usage2   index.html    Power_Usage3   SIV_Usage          SIV_Usage_V1_3     src_compare_tool_old
03_reactivity  06_tabsets  09_upload   Auto_DTC_old  Auto_DTC_Web2  GPIO_app     PowerSeq_app  sample-apps    SIV_Usage_V1_1     src_compare_tool2
```

I add my shiny app into `applicaion.yml`(see **specs**: **id:src_compare_tool3**) to let shinyproxy host. However, the page direct to shiny hello page, please kindly advise, thanks.

**4. applicaion.yml:**

```
proxy:
  title: Standalone Docker Engine with euler Example
  port: 8080
  authentication: simple
  admin-groups: admins
  users:
  - name: admin
    password: admin
    groups: admins
  docker:
    url: http://localhost:2375
  specs:
  - id: euler
    display-name: Hello Application
    container-cmd: ["R", "-e", "shinyproxy::run_01_hello()"]
    container-image: openanalytics/shinyproxy-demo
    port: 3838
    access-groups: admins
  - id: src_compare_tool3
    display-name: src_compare_tool3
    docker-cmd: ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/srv/shiny-server/src_compare_tool3')"]
    container-image: piko0306/data_analysis:SIV_src_compare_V1_3_ini_powerSeq2_GPIO_new_autoRout_0514
    port: 3838
    access-groups: admins     


logging:
  file:
    shinyproxy.log
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I finally overcome the issue:

```
  - id: src_compare_tool3
    display-name: src_compare_tool3        
    container-cmd: ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/srv/shiny-server/src_compare_tool3', host = '0.0.0.0', port = 3838, launch.browser = FALSE, quiet = TRUE)"]  
    container-image: piko0306/data_analysis:SIV_src_compare_V1_3_ini_powerSeq2_GPIO_new_autoRout_0514
    port: 3838
    access-groups: admins
```